# how to implement carService in ApiController? What is wrong in my code?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have created `carService` with only one method:

```
public interface CarService {
    String getName();
}
```

I added CarServiceImpl

```
@Component
public class CarServiceImpl implements CarService {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Fiat";
    }
}
```

Why does my method String getCarServiceIml not work, I don't got fiat?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/car")
public class ApiController {

   @Autowired
   private CarServiceImpl carServiceImpl;

   public String getCarServiceImpl() {
        return carServiceImpl.getName();
    }
}
```

When I visit `localhost:8080/car`, I got Whitelabel Error Page:

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Jan 10 11:20:26 CET 2018 There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). No message available
```

but I expected Fiat.

Comment: then what do you get?

Comment: Does your component-scan working correctly?

Comment: You should add `@RequestMapping` on your getCarServiceImpl method

Comment: *"After I got Whitelabel Error Page"*: this alone is useless - what's the stack trace logged in the console?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would change code for this:

```
@Service
public class CarServiceImpl implements CarService {

   @Override
   public String getName() {
      return "Fiat";
   }
}
```

And this Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/car")
public class ApiController {

    @Autowired
    private CarService carService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path="/name")
    public String getCarName() {
        return carService.getName();
    }
 }
```

If your SpringBoot configuration it's ok, this may be work fine, check if you put @ComponentScan in your Application main class, with your base package.